# How to `insert into` with select using `group by` and having a unique constraint key in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct, sql-insert

I am trying to `insert into` a table, 5 values from other 2 tables, but when I
try to insert them, Oracle sends me a message that I am violating the unique key restriction, what I do not understand why I have this problem if I am using the `distinct` clause in the select.

Thanks

My query:

```
  insert into grados_salariales (Department_id,
  Department_name,Sumatoria,Sal_minimo,Sal_maximo)
  Select distinct departments.department_id,
  departments.department_name,
  sum(employees.salary),min(employees.salary),
  max(employees.salary)
  from employees,departments
  group by salary,department_name,
  departments.department_id;
```

This is the table that already exist and the unique key statement

```
create table
grados_salariales(
  Department_id number,
  Department_name varchar(50),
  Sumatoria number,
  Sal_minimo number,
  Sal_maximo number);




  Alter table grados_salariales
  add constraint  Department_id_pk
  primary key ( Department_id);
```

I would expect inserting the `department_id` without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select distinct d.department_id, d.department_name,
       sum(e.salary), min(e.salary),
       max(e.salary)
from employees e join
     departments d
     on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by e.salary, d.epartment_name, d.department_id;
```

The problem is the `salary` in the `group by`.  If you want one row per department, then you can do:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name,
       sum(e.salary), min(e.salary),
       max(e.salary)
from employees e join
     departments d
     on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_name, d.department_id;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases so your queries are easier to write and read.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.